# Why is the 'Find Element' operation in the WebDriver protocol implemented as a POST request despite being a read operation?

Tags: webdriver

in the [webdriver specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver2/#endpoints), seems like GET requests are being used for operations that retrieve data, and post requests are being used for operations that may alter the state of the browser (such as clicking, navigating and so on).
however, the [find element](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver2/#dfn-find-element) operation is specified as a post request despite of the fact it just for element retrieval.
I can't find a good reasonable explanation for that behaviour - why it's designed this way?